# Arquivo "biblioteca partilhada" não executa no Ubunto linux

Tags: javascript, linux, electron

Sou usuário iniciante no linux, criei um app com electronJs rodei funcionou super bem, mas quando eu compilo para arquitetura linux, gera um arquivo "biblioteca partilhada",mas quando eu executo aparece o seginte erro:[image: imagem do erro]
como faço para resolver, tem alguma biblioteca que precise ser atualizada ?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Veja se é isto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060402/electron-executable-not-recognized-by-nautilus/55064060

Comment: @bfavaretto É isso mesmo, consegui solucionar, muito obrigado irmão!!